# AngularJS JavaScript Syntax error for login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS. I am trying to implement simple login page using AngularJS. But it is throwing **Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [login(userName,]**. Please guide me with this.

index.html -

```
<div class="mainBdy" ng-controller="loginForm">
      <form ng-submit=login(userName, password)>
        <div class="userName">
          <label for="usrNm">USERNAME</label>
          <input type="text" id="usrNm" ng-model="userName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="password">
          <label for="pwd">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="pwd" ng-model="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btnSection">
          <button>LOGIN</button>
          <button>SIGN UP</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
```

Controller.js -

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('loginForm', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{name: "Neha", pwd: "Neha"}, {name: "Sneha", pwd: "Sneha"}];
$scope.login = function (userName, password) {
    if (userName === "Neha" && password === "Neha") {
        alert("Welcome");
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Login");
    }
}
});
```

Comment: follow this guide http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/submitting-ajax-forms-the-angularjs-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess you missed quotes, change:

```
<form ng-submit=login(userName, password)>
```

to

```
<form ng-submit="login(userName, password)">
```